# Write a Validation Rule based on criteria

Tags: validation-rule

Write a Validation Rule on `Account` object of Salesforce which creates an account only when Rating is "Hot". Also, After creating the account, when we need to update it, Rating can only be from Hot to Warm and then Warm to Cold and then COld to Hot.

I have done till here and unable to go ahead:-

```
AND(
    NOT(
        AND(
            ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Rating), "Hot"), 
            ISPICKVAL(Rating, "Warm")
        )
    ), 
    NOT(
        AND(
            ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Rating), "Warm"), 
            ISPICKVAL(Rating, "Cold")
        )
    ), 
    NOT(
        AND(
            ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Rating), "Cold"), 
            ISPICKVAL(Rating, "Hot")
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the [`ISNEW()`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_isnew.htm&type=5) function, which returns true for a new record and false for an update.

To add this to your formula, you'll need the following:

```
IF(ISNEW(),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Rating, "Hot"),
    ***your existing formula***
)
```

Comment: Thanks,
Here is the updated one:

OR((AND(ISNEW(), NOT(ISPICKVAL(Rating, "Hot")))),(OR((AND(NOT(ISNEW()),ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Rating), "Hot"), NOT(ISPICKVAL(Rating, "Warm")))),(AND(NOT(ISNEW()),ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Rating), "Warm"), NOT(ISPICKVAL(Rating, "Cold")))),(AND(NOT(ISNEW()),ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Rating), "Cold"), NOT(ISPICKVAL(Rating, "Hot")))))))